# Как в WebStorm автоформатировать php код?

Tags: webstorm

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что *CSS* и *HTML* файлы поддаются форматированию кода через <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+L</kbd>, а *PHP* почему-то игнорирует.

Может я где то настройки сбил? 
Что необходимо сделать, чтоб в *PHP* файлах тоже работало форматирование через горячие клавиши?

Comment: Это потому, что webstorm не предназначен для работы с PHP. Используйте phpstorm

Comment: Settings->Code Style->PHP - тут смотрели настройки

Comment: Что-то я не понял, что нужно настраивать в параметрах Code Style. В расширениях там вообще PHP не наблюдается. Это что если я работаю с php в процессе  верстки мне ещё и на phpStorm переходить надо ?

Comment: не наблюдается, т.к. в WebStorm вообще нет поддержки PHP. Так что да - если работаете с PHP, и нужна возможность форматировать, запускать, отлаживать и т.д. PHP код - переходите на PHPStorm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо использовать PhpStorm.

Потомму что webStorm - это ide предназначенная для редактирования js проектов. Для редактирования PHP файлов существует PhpStorm)

PhpStorm поддерживает так же редактирование js

Comment: Потомму что webStorm - это ide предназначенная для редактирования js проектов. Для редактирования PHP файлов существует PhpStorm)

PhpStorm поддерживает так же редактирование js

Comment: В ответе напишите, у вас там сейчас меньше слов, чем в этом комментарии

Comment: В WebStorm`е можно утсановить поддержку php-файлов?